# If $f(x) =\frac{1}{3} ( \frac {5}{f(x+2)}+f(x+1))$ then $\underset{x \to \infty}{\lim}f(x) = ?$

Tags: limits, functions, limits-without-lhopital

If $f(x) =\frac{1}{3} ( \frac {5}{f(x+2)}+f(x+1))$ and $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$    then $\underset{x \to \infty}{\lim}f(x) = ?$

can anyone please give me a hint to find it?

I know how to find the limit when the limit exists. But I have no idea how to prove it's existence.

Comment: Let the limit be $y$ so, $$3y^2=5+y^2$$

Comment: why would I suppose that limit will exist? First I should prove it's existence.@labbhattacharjee

Comment: It seems that the condition $f(x)>0$ for all $x$ is important. If I pick random starting values $f(0), f(1)$ I seem to get some negative values soon.

Comment: @GEdgar, I have a feeling that only constant function satisfies this, but didn't come up with proof yet.

Comment: @Ennar ... could be.  It is supposed to converge to 1.5811..., but if I start with $f(0)=1.5$ and $ f(1)=1.6$ I reach $f(14)<0$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists. Then we can prove that:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x+1)=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x+2)=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=k$$

Then by passing limits to the both sides of your equation we get:

$$k =\frac{1}{3} ( \frac {5}{k}+k)\Leftrightarrow 3k^2=5+k^2 \Leftrightarrow k^2=\frac{5}{2}$$

Since $f(x)>0$, $k=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)>0$. So you get the positive solution of the above.

Comment: So the other part of the proof would be to prove that the limit exists.

Comment: @GEdgar If the limit didn't exist then we wouldn't get any number for it. That means that since we found the above limit, then it is sure that the limit exists. Otherwise we would find an evaluation of the limit that we would not accept by the given information of the exercise!!

Comment: @Anastassis Kapetanakis, that is completely wrong. The whole calculation doesn't even make sense if the limit doesn't exist, so you can't use it as proof for existence.

Comment: @Ennar Well thinking of it one more time I understand what you mean by that! Although, without knowing that the limit exists we cannot find the existence of the limit! The exercise itself must give that to us! Furthermore I have dealt with problems like the above in the past and I have been told that that's the way we prove the existence of the limit! I now understand that that's wrong!